# How do I know how much tokens a GPT-3 request used?

Tags: gpt-3

I am building an app around GPT-3, and I would like to know how much tokens every request I make uses. Is this possible and how ?

Comment: The past tense of the question makes it sound like you're asking for the tokens _after_ a request is made. I'm guessing that's not what's being asked, but if anyone comes across this Q&A looking for the tokens after running a request, it's in the JSON response, in the `usage` object: https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions

Answer (score 10):

### Counting Tokens with Actual Tokenizer

To do this in python, first install the [transformers](https://pypi.org/project/transformers/) package to enable the [GPT-2 Tokenizer](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/gpt2#transformers.GPT2Tokenizer), which is [the same](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/4936856-what-are-tokens-and-how-to-count-them) tokenizer used for [GPT-3]:

> pip install transformers

Then, to tokenize the string "Hello world", you have a choice of using GPT2TokenizerFast or GPT2Tokenizer.

```py
from transformers import GPT2TokenizerFast\
tokenizer = GPT2TokenizerFast.from_pretrained("gpt2")\
number_of_tokens = len(tokenizer("Hello world")['input_ids'])
```

or

```py
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer\
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")\
number_of_tokens = len(tokenizer("Hello world")['input_ids'])
```

In either case, tokenizer() produces a python list of token representing the string, which can the be counted with len(). The [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/gpt2#transformers.GPT2Tokenizer) doesn't mention any differences in behavior between the two methods. I tested both methods on both text and code and they gave the same numbers. The from_pretrained methods are unpleasantly slow: 28s for GPT2Tokenizer, and 56s for GPT2TokenizerFast. The load time dominates the experience, so I suggest NOT using the "fast" method. (Note: the first time you run either of the from_pretrained methods, a 3MB model will be downloaded and installed, which takes a couple minutes.)

### Approximating Token Counts

The tokenizers are slow and heavy, but approximations can be made to go back and forth between them, using nothing but the number of characters or tokens. I developed the following approximations by observing the behavior of the GPT-2 tokenizer. They hold well for English text and python code. The 3rd and 4th functions are perhaps the most useful since they let us quickly fit a text in the GPT-3's token limit.

```py
import math
def nchars_to_ntokens_approx(nchars):
    #returns an estimate of #tokens corresponding to #characters nchars
    return max(0,int((nchars - 2)*math.exp(-1))) 

def ntokens_to_nchars_approx(ntokens):
    #returns an estimate of #characters corresponding to #tokens ntokens
    return max(0,int(ntokens*math.exp(1) ) + 2 )

def nchars_leq_ntokens_approx(maxTokens):
    #returns a number of characters very likely to correspond <= maxTokens
    sqrt_margin = 0.5
    lin_margin = 1.010175047 #= e - 1.001 - sqrt(1 - sqrt_margin) #ensures return 1 when maxTokens=1
    return max( 0, int(maxTokens*math.exp(1) - lin_margin - math.sqrt(max(0,maxTokens - sqrt_margin) ) )) 

def truncate_text_to_maxTokens_approx(text, maxTokens):
    #returns a truncation of text to make it (likely) fit within a token limit
    #So the output string is very likely to have <= maxTokens, no guarantees though.
    char_index = min( len(text), nchars_leq_ntokens_approx(maxTokens) )
    return text[:char_index]
```

Comment: It's pretty fast to me, almost instantaneous. I don't know why you got 56s.

Comment: Its making some network calls, so it depends on your network speed.  When I sit further from my wifi antenna it takes even longer.

Comment: Still, did you really mean 56s? or do you mean 56ms?

Comment: Yes, 56 seconds; as in almost a minute. It’s interesting that it runs fast for you. I wonder what’s going on.

Comment: I did time it and got 3.74 ms per call on a text with 2000 tokens using GPT2TokenizerFast. Specifically my text is `"hello world" * 1000`. This doesn't require internet access because the model is already downloaded. Maybe you don't have a GPU so it's very slow. But I don't see GPU usage going up on my laptop when running the code either. Not sure what's going on. It doesn't make sense that a tokenizer will be that slow.

Comment: I'm running on a machine with an Nvidia RTX A2000 GPU. The super slow part for me is the line tokenizer = GPT2TokenizerFast.from_pretrained("gpt2"), so has nothing to do with the prompt.

Comment: It still only takes 2.5 second to load the tokenizer for me. The tokenizer is already downloaded.

Comment: My best guess for the cause of this timing difference is that I'm running into an incompatibility between tensorflow (only able to handle Cuda <= v11.2) and my Cuda12 installation, and this is preventing the use of AVX2 FMA instructions. Loading the tokenizer throws warnings about this.

Comment: Amazing code! What is `init_offset` ?

Comment: Ah sorry, init_offset = 2. I'll edit that into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example from [openai-cookbook](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/How_to_count_tokens_with_tiktoken.ipynb) that worked perfectly for me:

```
import tiktoken


def num_tokens_from_string(string: str, encoding_name: str) -> int:
    """Returns the number of tokens in a text string."""
    encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding(encoding_name)
    num_tokens = len(encoding.encode(string))
    return num_tokens

num_tokens_from_string("tiktoken is great!", "gpt2")
>6
```

Answer (score 3):

OPEN-AI charges GPT-3 usage through tokens, this counts both the prompt and the answer. For OPEN-AI 750 words would have an equivalent of around 1000 tokens or a token to word ratio of 1.4 . Pricing of the token depends of the plan you are on.

I do not know of more accurate ways of estimating cost. Perhaps using GPT-2 tokenizer from Hugging face can help. I know the tokens from the GPT-2 tokenizer are accepted when passed to GPT-3 in the logit bias array, so there is a degree of equivalence between GPT-2 tokens and GPT-3 tokens.

However GPT-2 and GPT-3 models are different and GPT-3 famously has more parameters than GPT-3 so GPT-2 estimations are probably lower token wise. I am sure you can write a simple program that estimates the price by comparing prompts and token usage, but that might take some time.

Answer (score 1):

Code to count how much tokens a GPT-3 request used:

```
def count_tokens(input: str):
    tokenizer = GPT2TokenizerFast.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    res = tokenizer(input)['input_ids']
    return len(res)


print(count_tokens("Hello world"))
```

Comment: Keep the tokenizer initialization outside the function (e.g. in `__init__`) to make this run much faster.

Answer (score 1):

For C# users you can refer this git repo https://github.com/betalgo/openai
You can take the tokenizing elements (Tokenizer/GPT3) from the repo and create a helper in your codebase.
(Note* Ive used this tokenizer and is pretty much accurate but it isn't recommended for production use)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it with Python 3.
Then you can pass the model name or the encoding string. You can get the encoding, the tokens or the token count.

**token_helper.py:**

```
import tiktoken

def encoding_getter(encoding_type: str):
    """
    Returns the appropriate encoding based on the given encoding type (either an encoding string or a model name).
    """
    if "k_base" in encoding_type:
        return tiktoken.get_encoding(encoding_type)
    else:
        return tiktoken.encoding_for_model(encoding_type)

def tokenizer(string: str, encoding_type: str) -> list:
    """
    Returns the tokens in a text string using the specified encoding.
    """
    encoding = encoding_getter(encoding_type)
    tokens = encoding.encode(string)
    return tokens

def token_counter(string: str, encoding_type: str) -> int:
    """
    Returns the number of tokens in a text string using the specified encoding.
    """
    num_tokens = len(tokenizer(string, encoding_type))
    return num_tokens
```

Works like this

```
>>> import token_helper
>>> token_helper.token_counter("This string will be counted as tokens", "gpt-3.5-turbo"))
7
```